# dynamic scaffold doesn't workd

Tags: grails, scaffold

I have a domain like this:

```
package helloworld

 class User { 

    String name 
    int tuoi    
    String ho

     static constraints = {
     } 
}
```

and a controller:

```
 package helloworld

 class UserController { 
    def scaffold = true 
}
```

after i run project and browse to **localhost:8080/helloworld/user/** i just get a blank page. why doesn't it show the page that plugin scaffold create ? i am using grails 2.4.4 and jdk version 1.7

Comment: Does UserController follows the same naming convention as the User domain class??

Comment: thanks abdullah i think it does

Comment: And you definitely have the `scaffolding` plugin listed in your `BuildConfig.groovy`?

Comment: An instance field named `scaffold` will do nothing, it needs to be available on the class.
Better: `static scaffold = true`
Best: `static scaffold = User`

But if you're pages weren't being scaffolded, the fact that you got a blank page rather than a 404 suggests you may have other problems. Any relevant log messages?